# How do I add some HTML panels from my Modal to my web page the 'React way'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have 2 Components, `ApplicationOverview.js` and `ApplicationModal.jsx`. Basically, I have a button "Add Application" on my ApplicationOverview.js page which opens the Modal in which I want to fill in some input fields and upload an image there, which is then shown on the ApplicationOverview page as a panel through predefined HTML.

The way I currently implemented it is with the `.insertAdjacentHTML` method which works, but on the one hand I've been told that implementing it this way makes my page vulnerable to XSS, and on the other hand, events that are added like this are not working. Is there a safe way to let React handle this by passing the HTML to `ApplicationOverview.js` and append it to an existing div element? Nothing I have searched for so far has worked for me.

**ApplicationModal.jsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import placeholder from "../icons/placeholder.png";

var name = "";
var comment = "";
var filename = "";
var id = 0;

const ApplicationModal = ({ setOpen }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");
  const [stateComment, setStateComment] = React.useState(placeholder);
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState({placeholder});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleEscapeKey(event) {
      if (event.code === "Escape") {
        setOpen(false);
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleEscapeKey);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleEscapeKey);
  });

  const handleComment = (e) => {
    setStateComment(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };

//Method which adds new panels to ApplicationOverview.js
  const addNewApplication = () => {
    if (state !== "" && stateComment !== "") {
      document
        .getElementById("center")
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          "beforeend",
          `<div class='overview-box' id=${id}> <img class='image' src=${file} alt='placeholder'/> <div class='box-content'><h3 class='overview-h3' id='new-headline'>${state}</h3> <p class='overview-p'>${stateComment}</p><h3 class='overview-h3-second'>Connected Products</h3><h1 class='overview-h1-second'> ?/? <p class='overview-p-second'>Online</p> </h1> <div class='module-button' id='configure'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary'></button> <div class='button-animation'></div> <div class='button-content'> <span class='content-text'>Configure</span> </div> </div> </div> </div>`
        );
      id++;
      setOpen(false);
    } else if (state === "" && stateComment !== "") {
      document
        .getElementById("center")
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          "beforeend",
          `<div class='overview-box' id = ${id}> <img class='image' src=${file} alt='placeholder'/> <div class='box-content'><h3 class='overview-h3' id='new-headline'>${state}</h3> <p class='overview-p'>${stateComment}</p><h3 class='overview-h3-second'>Connected Products</h3><h1 class='overview-h1-second'> ?/? <p class='overview-p-second'>Online</p> </h1> <div class='module-button' id='configure'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary'></button> <div class='button-animation'></div> <div class='button-content'> <span class='content-text'>Configure</span> </div> </div> </div> </div>`
        );
      id++;
      setOpen(false);
    } else if (state !== "" && stateComment === "") {
      document
        .getElementById("center")
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          "beforeend",
          `<div class='overview-box' id=${id}> <img class='image' src=${file} alt='placeholder'/> <div class='box-content'><h3 class='overview-h3' id='new-headline'>${state}</h3> <p class='overview-p'>${stateComment}</p><h3 class='overview-h3-second'>Connected Products</h3><h1 class='overview-h1-second'> ?/? <p class='overview-p-second'>Online</p> </h1> <div class='module-button' id='configure'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary'></button> <div class='button-animation'></div> <div class='button-content'> <span class='content-text'>Configure</span> </div> </div> </div> </div>`
        );
      id++;
      setOpen(false);
    } else {
      alert("Please fill in atleast one value.");
    }
  };

  function openDialog() {
    document.getElementById("inputUpload").click();
  }

  function loadFile(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files);
    setFile(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    
  })

  name = state;
  comment = stateComment;
  filename = file;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="modalDark" style={{ paddingRight: "250px" }}>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content" style={{ width: "800px" }}>
            <div class="modal-close">
              <div class="module-button" style={{ left: "750px" }}>
                <button
                  class="btn btn-link "
                  onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                ></button>
                <div class="button-animation"></div>
                <div class="button-content new">
                  <i class="icon icon-dc_close"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h3>Add new Application</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div
                class="module-input form-group has-placeholder"
                data-plugin="moduleInput"
                style={{ bottom: "60px", width: "350px" }}
              >
                <label for="demo-default">Customer Name</label>
                <div class="input-animation-wrapper">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="demo-default"
                    class="form-control "
                    value={state}
                    maxLength="42"
                    placeholder="[Application Name]"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                  />
                  <div class="input-animation"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div
                class="module-textarea form-group floating-label has-placeholder"
                data-plugin="moduleInput"
                style={{ bottom: "60px" }}
              >
                <label for="demo-3">Customer Short text</label>
                <div
                  class="input-animation-wrapper"
                  style={{ width: "350px" }}
                >
                  <textarea
                    id="demo-3"
                    class="form-control"
                    rows="9"
                    placeholder="Short description of Customer; max. 280 characters"
                    maxLength={180}
                    value={stateComment}
                    onChange={(e) => handleComment(e)}
                    style={{ width: "350px" }}
                  ></textarea>
                  <div class="label-area"></div>
                  <div class="input-animation"></div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <img
                class="image"
                alt="Customer Logo"
                id="logo"
                src={file}
                style={{
                  left: "420px",
                  bottom: "280px",
                  position: "absolute",
                  height: "250px",
                }}
              />

              <div
                class="module-button"
                style={{
                  left: "500px",
                  bottom: "200px",
                  position: "absolute",
                  zIndex: "1",
                }}
              >
                <button
                  type="file"
                  class="btn btn-light"
                  onClick={() => openDialog()}
                  id="fileUpload"
                >
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    hidden={true}
                    accept="image/*"
                    id="inputUpload"
                    onChange={(e) => loadFile(e)}
                  ></input>
                </button>
                <div class="button-animation"> </div>
                <div class="button-content">
                  <span class="content-text">Upload Logo</span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div
                class="module-button"
                style={{ bottom: "50px", width: "100px", textAlign: "center" }}
              >
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-secondary btn"
                  onClick={() => addNewApplication()}
                  id="adding"
                ></button>
                <div class="button-animation"></div>
                <div class="button-content">
                  <span class="content-text">Add</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ApplicationModal;

export { name, comment, filename };
```

**ApplicationOverview.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import placeholder from "../icons/placeholder.png";

import ApplicationModal from "../components/ApplicationModal.jsx";

const ApplicationOverview = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      {open && <ApplicationModal setOpen={setOpen} />}
      <div class="component-headline">
        <h4 style={{ color: "gray", display: "inline" }}>
          Application overview
        </h4>
        <div
          class="module-button"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "rgb(18,205,212,255)",
            borderRadius: "12px",
            marginLeft: "1032px",
          }}
          onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
        >
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
          <div class="button-animation"></div>
          <div
            class="button-content"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "rgb(18,205,212,255)",
              borderRadius: "12px",
            }}
          >
            <span class="content-text" style={{ color: "black" }}>
              Add Application
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr style={{ marginTop: "-20px" }} />

      <!-- This is where the added content should be appended to, below are three examples -->
      <!-- of hardcoded panels that should be normally added through the Modal" -->
      <div class="center-content" id="center">
        <div class="overview-box">
          <img
            class="image"
            src={placeholder}
            alt="placeholder"
          />
          <div class="box-content">
            <h3 class="overview-h3">Press</h3>
            <p class="overview-p">This Application is used for maintenance</p>
            <h3 class="overview-h3-second">Connected Products</h3>
            <h1 class="overview-h1-second">
              ?/?
              <p class="overview-p-second">Online</p>
            </h1>

            <div class="module-button" id="configure">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
              <div class="button-animation"></div>
              <div class="button-content">
                <span class="content-text">Configure</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overview-box">
          <img
            class="image"
            src={placeholder}
            alt="placeholder"
          />
          <div class="box-content">
            <h3 class="overview-h3">Tooling Machine</h3>
            <p class="overview-p">
              This Application is used for drilling records
            </p>
            <h3 class="overview-h3-second">Connected Products</h3>
            <h1 class="overview-h1-second">
              ?/?
              <p class="overview-p-second">Online</p>
            </h1>

            <div class="module-button" id="configure">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
              <div class="button-animation"></div>
              <div class="button-content">
                <span class="content-text">Configure</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="overview-box">
          <img
            class="image"
            src={placeholder}
            alt="placeholder"
          />
          <div class="box-content">
            <h3 class="overview-h3">Storing Unit</h3>
            <p class="overview-p">
              This Application is used to store parameters
            </p>
            <h3 class="overview-h3-second">Connected Products</h3>
            <h1 class="overview-h1-second">
              ?/?
              <p class="overview-p-second">Online</p>
            </h1>

            <div class="module-button" id="configure">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
              <div class="button-animation"></div>
              <div class="button-content">
                <span class="content-text">Configure</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ApplicationOverview;
```

[Modal Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYF11.png)

[ApplicationOverview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pnV8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your useState in the ApplicationOverview.js and pass them as props to the ApplicationModal. So when the applicationModal set the useState the ApplicationOverview has the data and can simply display it.
in your ApplicationOverview:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState("");
  const [stateComment, setStateComment] = React.useState(placeholder);
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState({placeholder});

return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      {open && <ApplicationModal setOpen={setOpen} setState={setState} state={state} setFile={setFile} file={file} setStateComment={setStateComment} stateComment={stateComment}/>
    rest of your HTML
   
)
```

then where you want to display the result in the ApplicationOverview you can:

```
{state && stateComment { display what you want}}
```

Comment: Almost! This is very close to what I want to achieve, the problem is the user should only be able to see the panel after the "Add" Button has been clicked in the ApplicationModal. As of now, if the user clicks on the close button in the top right corner of the modal, but filled in some values into the input fields, the panel will stay on the page and adding another panel will just result in the current panel being changed. I will add two screenshots of what exactly should happen.

Comment: You can have a local state in your ApplicationModal and then only call the setter to pass the data to the ApplicationOverview when the 'Add' button is clicked

Comment: Now the application behaves like it should, when I click on 'Add' the panel is added to ApplicationOverview and the values are resetted whenever I open up a new Modal. However, the only problem that still remains is that when I try to add a second panel, it just changes the values of the first panel after clicking on the Add button. Do you know / can you give me an example of how to fix that?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the issue. Maybe make a new question with your new code

Comment: [There you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386842/how-to-add-multiple-div-panels-to-my-main-page-in-react) (note that I changed it a little bit from what you suggested before since I wasn't sure either what exactly to do)